# Client DNS with multiple VPN connections

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vpn, split-tunnel

I have a scenario where Windows client devices will be connected to two different VPN networks. The remote networks each have separate address spaces, `10.0.0.0/16` and `10.20.0.0/16` respectively. IP routes are established on the client machine so that traffic for those IP ranges are sent over the correct VPN connections, and all other traffic is sent over the internet as normal.

Here's where our fun starts. Each network also hosts it's own Active Directory domain, which I'll call `DomainA.com` and `DomainB.com`. Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to access resources in either domain by FQDN, not just IP address. So, for example, `server.DomainA.com` would resolve to `10.0.0.50` and be contacted over the first VPN connection, and `server.DomainB.com` would resolve to `10.20.0.50` and be contacted over the second VPN.

Of course, the DNS servers in the `10.0.0.0/16` network don't know anything about `DomainB.com`, and the DNS servers in the `10.20.0.0/16` network don't know anything about `DomainA`.com. And the internet DNS doesn't know the correct address of either domain.

In a scenario like this, how would you go about getting DNS resolution to work for `DomainA.com`, `DomainB.com` and the internet? I feel like I should be able to tell Windows "Use X DNS server for `DomainA.com`" and "Use Y DNS server for `DomainB.com`". Is there any way to do that? If not, is there some other change I could make, either to the client devices or the remote networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. You can use the Windows [Name Resolution Policy Table (NPRT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn593632(v=ws.11)). This is, essentially, *exactly* what is requested in the question: a way to tell Windows to use a specific DNS server for a specific domain. You can configure NRPT using Group Policy, but in my case I configured it using PowerShell, specifically [Add-DnsClientNrptRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/add-dnsclientnrptrule).

Below is my final PowerShell script for managing a given NRPT rule:

```
$Domain = ".DomainA.com"
[string[]]$NameServers = "10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"

Get-DnsClientNrptRule | Where Namespace -eq $Domain | ForEach-Object {Remove-DnsClientNrptRule -Name $_.Name -Force}
Add-DnsClientNrptRule -Namespace $Domain -NameServers $NameServers
```

(Note the `.` at the start of the domain name string.)

I start by deleting any existing rules for that domain, because NRPT rules don't override each other. Instead, a conflict results in no rule being applied.

As another side note, I've read that `nslookup` doesn't respect NRPT rules. So don't be fooled by that if you are testing this out. In my tests `ping`, `mstsc` and other Windows components work perfectly with these rules in place.